# Question about limit points and neighbourhoods

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$O$ is an open set in $\mathbb R^n$ and $E$ is an open set in $\mathbb R^n$ which is contained in $O$. If $z \in O$ is a limit point of $E$, then prove that there exists $y \in E$ and $r > 0$ such that $z \in B(y,r) \subseteq B(y,2r) \subseteq O$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Since $z\in O$, there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(z,\epsilon)\subseteq O$. Now observe that $E\cap B(z,\epsilon/2)\ne\varnothing$; make proper use of this, and you’ll be able to use $r=\epsilon/2$.